# django ugettext_lazy and ugettext not working in form field label

Tags: python, django

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy,ugettext as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Page, HomeBanner, ColorBox,IconBox,HomeVideo
from django.db.models import Q

class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
  title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'label':ugettext_lazy('Title'),'class':'form-control'}))

  title_small = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'label':_('Title Small'),'class':'form-control'}),required=False)

  status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(
    ('draft', _('draft')),
    ('published', _('published')),
    ('deleted', _('deleted')),
  ), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'label':_('Status'),'class':'form-control'}),required=True)
```

they are working on choices but not working in label definition.

what is going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What exactly are they doing or not doing?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass [`label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#label) as an argument to the form, not as a widget attribute.

```
class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(label=ugettext_lazy('Title'),
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                            )
    ...
```